# Calculating a baseline probability model for images

Tags: machine-learning, probability, density-function

I'm a newbie to statistics, so I apologize if this question is trivial.

I'm trying to build a distribution that can predict a specific set of images. But first, I need a baseline - so, I decided to model a normal distribution on the images and see the average Log PDF of each image with respect to that normal distribution.

How I've tried to achieve this so far is to take the average pixel, use that as my mean, and take the standard deviation of the pixels from that mean and use it as my standard deviation. That gives me a normal distribution, but it doesn't let me calculate the probability of a whole image - just each individual pixel. Can I just take the product of the pdf of each pixel to get the probability of the whole image? That feels right to me, but I don't know statistics well enough to trust myself.

But even more fundamentally, is this the best way of modelling a "baseline" normal distribution on these images? Should I be using some other distribution, possibly a multinomial distribution? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: pixel values of natural images are clearly not independent, but as a baseline model it seems ok